# VCenter: REST API: How to upload ova to content Library

Tags: rest, api, vmware, vcenter, ova

Iam trying to create a VM from ova using REST API. I can do this using this Rest API:

```
https://vcenter_ip/rest/com/vmware/vcenter/ovf/library-item/id:<library_item_id_ie_ova_item>?~action=deploy
```

To do this, I uploaded the ova through VSphere client. (Content library->Select library ->Import Item-> Select .ovf file from local -> (prompts to select reference files) select dependent .vmdk from local)

But I want to perform the upload through Rest API.

The steps I have done so far are:

1. Create a Library

> URL: https://vcenter_ip/rest/com/vmware/content/local-library

```
Method: POST
Headers:
   Key:Content-Type 
   value: application/json
Request Body:
{
    "create_spec": {
        "name": "CL1",
        "description": "CL1 Desc",
        "publish_info": {
            "authentication_method": "NONE",
            "persist_json_enabled": false,
            "published": false
        },
        "storage_backings": [
            {
                "datastore_id": "datastore-144",
                "type": "DATASTORE"
            }
        ],
        "type": "LOCAL"
    }
}
```

2. Create a Library Item

> URL:https://vcenter_ip/rest/com/vmware/content/library/item

```
Method: POST
Headers:
   Key:Content-Type 
   value: application/json

Request Body:
{
  "create_spec": {
    "library_id": "<library_id",
    "description": "mydesc",
    "name": "Damn Small Linux",
    "type": "ovf"
  }
}
```

3. Create new update Session

> URL:
>   https://vcenter_ip/rest/com/vmware/content/library/item/update-session

```
Method: POST
Headers:
   Key:Content-Type 
   value: application/json

Request Body:
{
  "create_spec":{
  "library_item_id": "<lib_item_id>"
  }
}

Response:
{
  "value": "26f143a2-fb9d-4ed9-bd5f-c7be5825ee37:ec4f8df0-249f-4887-ab84-0933f86e106c"
}
```

Next, I try to upload the files to content-library item and that is where Iam facing issues.

4. To upload ovf

4(a). request endpoint to upload .ovf file

> URL:https://vcenter_ip/rest/com/vmware/content/library/item/updatesession/file/id:f539fb7e-af8f-4cc8-ad66-cdcbd80f5dc4%3Aec4f8df0-249f-4887-ab84-0933f86e106c?~action=add

```
Method: POST
Headers:
   Key:Content-Type 
   value: application/json
   Key:update_session_id    
   value: 26f143a2-fb9d-4ed9-bd5f-c7be5825ee37:ec4f8df0-249f-4887-ab84-0933f86e106c

{
  "file_spec": {
    "source_type": "PUSH",
    "name": "Damn Small Linux.ovf",
    "size": 9
  }
}
```

Response Body:

```
{
  "value": {
    "bytes_transferred": 0,
    "upload_endpoint": {
      "uri": "https://<vcenter_ip>:443/cls/data/1a5129a1-87e8-4650-855d-9041c493c475/Damn%20Small%20Linux.ovf"
    },
    "name": "Damn Small Linux.ovf",
    "source_type": "PUSH",
    "status": "WAITING_FOR_TRANSFER"
  }
}
```

4(b). Uploading to that URI with put request with file uploaded as multipart form data (I did this with postman- I did the rest of the calls through Vcenter api explorer)

[image]

4(c). Validate file in update session

```
URL: https://vcenter_ip/rest/com/vmware/content/library/item/updatesession/file/id:26f143a2-fb9d-4ed9-bd5f-c7be5825ee37%3Aec4f8df0-249f-4887-ab84-0933f86e106c?~action=validate
Method: POST
Headers:
   Key:Content-Type 
   value: application/json
   Key:update_session_id    
   value: 26f143a2-fb9d-4ed9-bd5f-c7be5825ee37:ec4f8df0-249f-4887-ab84-0933f86e106c

Response Body: 
{
  "value": {
    "has_errors": true,
    "invalid_files": [
      {
        "error_message": {
          "args": [
            "Damn Small Linux.ovf",
            "1:1:PARSE_ERROR: Parse error: Unexpected character '-' (code 45) in prolog; expected '<'\r\n at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1].\r\n"
          ],
          "default_message": "File Damn Small Linux.ovf was considered invalid. Reason: 1:1:PARSE_ERROR: Parse error: Unexpected character '-' (code 45) in prolog; expected '<'\r\n at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1].\r\n.",
          "id": "com.vmware.vdcs.cls-main.update_session_file_validation"
        },
        "name": "Damn Small Linux.ovf"
      }
    ],
    "missing_files": []
  }
}
```

But this is the same file I have uploaded while uploading through vsphere client successfully.

What is the issue here?
And how do I next upload a reference .vmdk following this?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I'll put up the answer in case someone runs into this:

To get this to work, two settings are required in your data upload `PUT`:

1. Set headers `Content-Type` as `application/octet-stream`
2. Under body, ensure you select **binary** for your (ovf) file

Comment: Can you please explain what does the second point mean and jiwni can attain this ?

Comment: @LearningPhase I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. This is RE using Postman & the configuration to use. If programmatically, it's important to set the correct Content-Type.